# How to use the google font v2 API import url in sass file with webpack laravel mix?

Tags: webpack, sass, laravel-mix, google-font-api

I'm trying to import a [google font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Inter:wght@500;600;700;800;900) into my a sass file, right at the top before all other styles.

I am using [webpack laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix), and I am also using the [google font v2 API link](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2).

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
```

The problem with the new css2 link, it contains semi-colons and creates css parse errors.

The sass file actually compiles fine, but this is the output of the css file...

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@500;

600;700;800;900&display=swap);@charset "UTF-8";
```

Which is not valid, and the main fonts do not work, only the fallback font `san-serif` works.

[image]

---

The only way I've found to temporarily get round this problem is to use the old url. But I would rather use the latest google v2 url.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:500,600,700,800,900");
```