# node-sass custom importer for file from the web not working

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I am trying to import a stylesheet from Google Fonts into a stylesheet  to avoid the eytra request later on.

My `main.scss` file starts with

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@400;700&display=swap";
```

and I expect the resulting `main.css` to start with

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v17/S6u8w4BMUTPHjxswWw.ttf) format('truetype');
}
/* etc */
```

For this I have the following script:

```
var scss = require("node-sass");
var https = require('https');

function compile(filePath, dirs, callback){
  scss.render({
    file: filePath,
    includePaths: dirs,
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    sourceMap: false,
    importer: [
      function(url, prev, done) {
        if (url.startsWith('https')) {
          https.get(url, (res) => {
            let contents = '';
            res.on('data', (d) => contents += d);
            res.on('end', () => {
              console.log('scss')
              done({contents})
            });         
          });
        }
        return null;
      }
    ]
  }, function (e, css) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error)
    }
    callback(null, css.css)
  });
}

compile('main.scss', null, (e, d)=>{console.log(d.toString())})
```

The [node-sass spec](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api#importer) says the content should be delivered back as

> An object with the key `contents` whose value is the contents of a stylesheet (in SCSS syntax). This causes Sass to load that stylesheet’s contents.

I can see that the importer function is called, resolves the request and has the wanted stylesheet text in the `contents` variable. The output is written to the console, but still has the original `@import` line.

Where does this go wrong?

**Edit:** If using node-sass, node crashes with the message `Speicherzugriffsfehler`. After changing the used library to [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), the crash does not happen, but the error of the not-resolved import remains.

Equally, trying to use a dummy static rule `.bla {--blubb: green;}` as the returned contents did not work.

Comment: I had the same issue with this too I think [see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505687/how-to-use-the-google-font-v2-api-import-url-in-sass-file-with-webpack-laravel-m). The only way I got round the issue was to use google font v1 API import url in sass file.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you did not try to exchange the `@import` for the resolved `@font-face`, but only had problems with the url syntax. This is not the issue here.

Comment: It’s just odd the similarities with the compiled css leaving the sass @import syntax. As soon as switched the to v1 api url. It compiled properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after examining the dart-sass library a bit closer. It seems URLs that start with the `http(s)://` protocol are never passed to the importer function.

So you have to trick it a bit, and this is not a generalized solution.

In the `main.scss` file, shorten the URL of the protocol:

```
@import "fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@400;700&display=swap";
```

Then, catch the `fonts` at the begining in the importer function:

```
    importer: function(url, prev, done) {
      if (url.startsWith('fonts')) {
        https.get('https://' + url, (res) => {
          let contents = '';
          res.on('data', (d) => contents += d);
          res.on('end', () => done({contents}));
        });
      }
    },
```

Note an important difference: There is no `return null;` after the `if` clause. This was causing the importer result to be passed, despite it loading the file contents correctly.

The whole solution only works with [(dart-)sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), not with node-sass, which ends in an infinite loop for some reason.